What type literary device is this (with the word seems)?

When Josie said this, the Mother's face broke into a smile. The Mother didn't smile often, but when she did, her smile was surprisingly like Josie's: her whole face seemed to overflow with kindness, and the same creases that usually created such a tense expression would refold into ones of humor and gentleness. 'I have to admit. My cello-playing, even at its glorious best, sounded like Dracula's grandmother. But your use of color is more like, well, a pond on a summer's evening. Something like that. You do beautiful things with color, Josie. Things no one else even thought about.'
— Klara and the Sun, Kazuo Ishiguro, 2021

What literary device is there in the bold sentence?

The first part (her smile was surprisingly like Josie's) isn't really a "literary device" - it's just descriptive writing. The second part (her whole face seemed to overflow with kindness) is essentially a metaphoric reference equating plasticity of facial expression with the flow of rising / spilling liquid. It's figurative language, if you will.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The word 'seemed' tells you that there was no kindness flowing exactly, but anyone watching could imagine that it looked that way. English is so filled with idioms that we hardly notice we are not being literal or that we're using a literary device. So figurative that speakers say literally to express figurative language that is closer to being literal when it's still not literal.

Is the Q about the difference between metaphor and simile, with the latter using explicit comparison?
